# "Sense of Calm" vs "Sense of calmness" & "Works are" vs "work is"

Tags: grammaticality

I came across a sentence

> his works are invariably imbued with a sense of calm and serenity

Now in my opinion (for which I do not have any concrete reason) it should've been "sense of calmness". Apart from this should it be *his* **work is** *invariably*?

Am I wrong?

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary to confirm whether the word 'calm' can be used as an abstract noun as well as being an adjective?  If it could not, that would be a good reason for objecting to its use in this context.  But it can.  There are other grounds for objection, such as that it uses two nouns, meaning pretty well the same thing where one is sufficient.  But that is a matter of style father than grammar or semantics, and so not strictly relevant to ELU.

Comment: Actually, you are wrong. See Tuffy's remark.

Comment: Either of 'His works are' and 'His work is' are fine here. The former focuses the reader's mind on the individual works (or, if not known, the fact that there are individual works) rather than the referent's output. I prefer 'calmness' to 'calm' here, as it is less abrupt. But as @Tuffy says, there's a tautology. Though they're not always unacceptable, 'a sense of calmness and calmness' is awful.

Comment: _His works_ unambiguously means "the various pieces of art that he has created, individually". "His work" might mean the same things collectively, but it could also refer to other things, eg "his job". In this context, either would do.